# Como converter esse caractere no PostgreSQL?

Tags: delphi, postgresql, utf-8, latin1

Estou usando DelphiXE e PostgreSQL, acontece que preciso inserir uns caracteres na base de dados que não são aceitos em LATIN1.

Minha base é UTF-8, mas como o o sistema vem sendo transportado desde a versão Delphi6, e base antiga estou usando LATIN1, não posso simplesmente mudar de LATIN1 pata UTF-8 porque o Delphi Grita de tudo quanto é lado.

Eu consigo inserir os Dados do PGAdmin normal, mas quando tento ler no delphi ele reclama que não existe o caractere correspondente em LATIN1.

O Caracter é tipo esse "ß-Cloropreno" e "α,α''Diamina m-xileno"

Estou numa sinuca de Bico

Vocês tem alguma sugestão?

Obs.: Esses são documentos a serem enviados ao eSocial então tenho que enviar da forma como ele querem, senão da recusa... ai ja viu né

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html), o PostgreSQL suporta conversão automática de UTF-8 para LATIN1, bastando apenas informar o *character set* do seu *client*, no caso a aplicação Delphi.

Para isso você tem algumas opções. Se puder alterar a aplicação, pode definir o `client_encoding` logo após efetuar a conexão, assim tudo virá em LATIN1:

```
set client_encoding to 'LATIN1';
```

Outra possibilidade, para evitar qualquer alteração na aplicação,você pode também alterar o `client_encoding` padrão do usuário dela:

```
alter user usuario_latin1 set client encoding to 'LATIN1';
```

Claro, para isso é melhor que ela tenha um usuário exclusivo, separado daquele utilizado pelos clients que entendem UTF-8.

Comment: Nunks, matou a pau, eu estava tentando fazer isso com o usuário postgres e não estava dando certo, achava que não era possível, como esse sistema é específico e somente para essa empresa estava usando o usuário postgres mesmo, seu post me fez abrir a mente e resolvi criar um novo usuário e alterei conforme sua dica, deu certinho, ele não reclama e mostra o caractere corretamente, de quebra isso vai me resolver outro problema que dava quando o cara copiava e colava texto do word que vinha com caracteres UTF-8, muito obrigado!

Comment: Nunks, tentei colocar @ antes do teu login mas o stack não deixa, deve ter algum filtro, seu login deve ser palavra reservada

Comment: @Marcelo poizé, não sei pq meu nick tem algumas estranhezas com o SO, haha. Enfim, a gente tende mesmo a esquecer que muitos parametros do PostgreSQL funcionam no nível de usuário e podem muito bem servir pra resolver conflitos que apareceriam se tivéssemos que mudar opções globais. Que bom que pude ajudar =)