# Problemas com encoding em Consulta ao Banco de Dados

Tags: postgresql, codificação-de-caracteres, jsonb

Ao tentar executar um `SELECT`, usando campos que guardam dados na estrutura JSON, vejo um problema com o dados que possa vir:

```
SELECT tbl_pf.nome,
       tbl_pf.adicionais::JSONB->'recebeTaxa' AS localTaxa
FROM   tbl_pf;
```

Ao buscar o campo com a tratativa de trazer apenas parte do JSON gravado, vejo este erro:

> ERROR:  unsupported Unicode escape sequence
>     DETAIL:  Unicode escape values cannot be used for code point values above 007F when the server encoding is not UTF8.

Ao buscar o campo JSON completo, não há erro.

Essa busca é feita no terminal, onde já há a configuração para tratar de dados UTF8 vindo do banco de dados. (Esse tipo de consulta consigo usar em outras tabelas com dados em JSON, com conteúdo já tratado, incluindo dados numéricos).

Queria saber se este problema é apenas no terminal, que não consegue identificar o encode do banco, ou o BD também tem "culpa no cartório", já que usando uma rotina em PHP para testes, o erro foi o mesmo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mensagem de erro colada na pergunta vem do PostgreSQL, e indica que o banco de dados em questão não está no *encoding* UTF-8.

A [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-json.html) indica que não é possível suportar completamente a especificação JSON sem que o banco de dados esteja codificado em UTF-8, já que a [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) determina que valores em JSON utilizem esse *character set* (na prática também suporta UTF-16 e UTF-32, mas ressalta que UTF-8 é proporciona melhor interoperabilidade entre sistemas).

Mais especificamente para o seu caso, a mesma página da documentação esclarece:

> *However, the input function for jsonb is stricter: it disallows Unicode escapes for non-ASCII characters (those above U+007F) unless the database encoding is UTF8.*

Ou seja, se seu *database* não possuir *encoding* UTF8, você obterá esses erros de conversão para caracteres "extendidos" toda vez que for extraí-los de um campo jsonb, visto não ser possível convertê-los ao *charset* do banco em questão para manipulação dos dados. Acredito que a ausência de erros ao consultar o campo como um todo está no fato de ele ser tratado simplesmente como texto, sem necessidade de efetuar um *parse* para buscar determinadas propriedades.

Sendo assim, seja na linha de comando ou qualquer outro client utilizado, o Postgres deverá retornar esse mesmo erro para a *query* apresentada. Sugiro que converta sua base para UTF8 afim de evitar quaisquer problemas de codificação com os tipos de dados json e jsonb.

Caso necessite que seu client "fale" com o banco em outro *encoding*, você pode definir o parâmetro `client_encoding` no momento da conexão ou nas configurações específicas do usuário, como nessa [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/294078/como-converter-esse-caractere-no-postgresql/294158#294158) aqui no SOP.